# bash adds escape chars when passing a string with quotes

Tags: string, bash

I'm trying to run a msyql command which includes a quoted string, for eg:

```
mysql -h host -u=user -p=pass -e "show tables" database.
```

Here I'm having difficulty to pass "show tables" with quotes to a fuction that executes the command.

```
run_cmd()  # Run a command
{
  local output=$1
  local timeout=$2
  shift 2
  ( $* > $output 2>&1 ) &
# ....
}

# Query mysql 

query_mysql(){
    local mysql_cmd=( "mysql -h $host --user=$user --password=$pass -e "show tables" $db")
    run_cmd $output $timeout "${mysql_cmd[@]}"
}
query_mysql
```

I tried many combinations, however the command get executed either without quotes or with multiple single/double/escape chars. In all cases the final command becomes invalid due to missing/additional quotes/chars.

few of my attempts & the final command:

```
"show tables"
mysql -h localhost --user=root --password=foo -e show tables db1 

'show tables'
mysql -h localhost --user=root --password=foo -e ''\''show' 'tables'\''' db1

\"show tables\"
mysql -h localhost --user=root --password=foo -e '"show' 'tables"' db1
```

Any suggestions to pass the quoted string as is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried double slashes?

Comment: With \\"show table\\" , I get  -> mysql -h localhost --user=root --password=foo -e '\show' 'table\' db1 (still the argument includes un-necessary ' chars :(

Comment: nope, I tried this and the command becomes "mysql -h localhost --user=root --password=foo -e '"show' 'table"' db1"

Comment: single quote the whole command

Comment: If I single quote the whole command, then variable expansion ($user,$host) wont work:(

Comment: Why are you passing the command as an array anyway ?

Comment: >>why do you put space before your command? Removing the space did not help, same results.

Comment: I'm using it for many other commands, so trying to use same format for  mysql_cmd as well.  and when it's an array, I can add additional details (other than the command) eg: a timeout value kill the process, output file etc..

Comment: mysql_cmd=$("command")
run_cmd $output $timeout $mysql_cmd

Comment: It removes the last portion when I tries to use "show tables" or "\"show tables\"". with single quotes, the result is same as earlier:(

Comment: how do you use it? show the whole variable with command

Comment: @SandyElms local mysql_cmd=("mysql -h $host --user=$user --password=$pass -e "\"show table\"" $db")
run_cmd $output $timeout $mysql_cmd
output: 
+ mysql -h localhost --user=root --password=foo -e '"show' 
With : \\"show table\\"  <= o/p same as above^^

'show table' 
output: mysql -h localhost --user=root --password=foo -e ''\''show' 'table'\''' db1

Comment: do you save some value to your mysql_cmd? what returns sql query? because if you store to mysql_cmd value you should  use it like this : local mysql_cmd=$("mysql -h $host --user=$user --password=$pass -e "\"show table\"" $db") . Don't forget about $ in front of the command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quote unrelated words inside the array assignment. So use

```
local mysql_cmd=( mysql -h "$host" --user="$user" --password="$pass" -e "show tables" "$db")
```

instead of

```
local mysql_cmd=( "mysql -h $host --user=$user --password=$pass -e "show tables" $db")
```

See the difference between yours

```
$ mysql_cmd=( "mysql -h $host --user=$user --password=$pass -e "show tables" $db")
$ printf %q\\n "${mysql_cmd[@]}"
mysql\ -h\ host\ --user=user\ --password=pass\ -e\ show
tables\ db
```

and mine

```
$ mysql_cmd=( mysql -h "$host" --user="$user" --password="$pass" -e "show tables" "$db")
$ printf %q\\n "${mysql_cmd[@]}"
mysql
-h
host
--user=user
--password=pass
-e
show\ tables
db
```

Also don't use unquoted `$*` when you execute the command. You probably want to use `"$@"` instead. So

```
( "$@" > $output 2>&1 ) &
```

which doesn't actually need the sub-shell `()` and can probably just be

```
"$@" > $output 2>&1 &
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for more details about why this array command usage needs to work this way (and why you were having such trouble with your attempts).

Comment: I'm still having trouble to get "show table" inside quotes, single quote (or escaping) does not seem to work

Comment: How are you seeing that you have that "trouble"? Does the command fail to run? Does mysql need those as literal quotes in the command itself? (I was assuming it just needed `show tables` as the argument to `-e` as one argument.)

Comment: command fails, mysql expects `show tables` in single/double quotes. (eg: `mysql <other options> -e "show tables" db_name` )

Comment: are you looking at `set -x` or `set -vx` debug/trace output? That output can be misleading. Good luck.

Comment: I'm also checking the output file which includes stdout&err, it shows the mysql help

Comment: When you run `mysql -e "show tables"` at the prompt mysql doesn't see the double quotes. The shell strips them before mysql sees the argument. What is in the output file when you use my array assignment and execution line? (You can add `set -x` at the top of the `run_cmd` function to see what is actually being run to find out more of what is going on.)